# Reactive forms with interfaces

Tags: angular

More of a question on best practice.
Let's say you have a form asking for Name and Age:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="sendMyForm(myForm)"><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" />
<hr />
<label>Age</label>
<select><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option></select></form>
```

Note that a dropdown is a number. Now, of course, this will by default be a string not a number as it's in a `<select>`.

My question is should I make an interface such as:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

And would you assign the interface somehow to the form first? Or on the model.value when you submit the form? I ask as the API would expect a number not a string of a number.

If you would assign the interface to the form upfront, please could you show how to do this?

Form set-up would be:

```
this.myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
            name: null,
            age: null
        });
```

Comment: time of API call you have verify the value

Comment: How are you retrieving the value of the selected option?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami I've just updated my question :) In this case it's a fresh form - not getting any values from the api.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward, please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

In our application we have interfaces representing the form type. And we have mappers which know how to map form value to entity and entity back to form value. If we hadn't the types for form, then our mapper would not be type safe. IMHO it is worth the effort to have types everywhere.

You can either add mapping between form value and service so that service expects the mapped type or make your service expect the form type and do the mapping inside the service.

Comment: So you map the interface to your values on submit?

Comment: yes, in `onSubmit` we take `formGroup.value` and map it to entity and service accepts the mapped type. in our case it is responsibility of the component that owns the form group.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[ngValue]` instead of `value` like below

```
<option [ngValue]="20">20</option>
<option [ngValue]="30">30</option>
```

Also, you need to put the `formControlName` on the `select` tag

```
<select formControlName="age">
```

You don't need to use any mappings and conversions.

To check the type, keep the below in the method which is triggered on submit

```
console.log('type of age is', typeof this.myForm.controls['age'].value) // gives number
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its long time after the question is asked.Just came across this question and I think I got a solution. Please check the below answer is what you are expecting.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="sendMyForm()"><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
<hr />
<label>Age</label>
<select formControlName="age"><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option></select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I have added a button in your code.

```
fBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  personModel: Person;

  myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
      name: this.fBuilder.control(''),
      age: this.fBuilder.control(0)
  });
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  sendMyForm(){
    this.personModel = Object.assign({}, this.myForm.value);
    console.log(this.personModel);
  }
```

regarding your question

> "And would you assign the interface somehow to the form first?" - No.
> As the reactive forms will manage the data binding its own. Instead
> once the form is submitted, I took the values and mapped to the
> interface.